# Grails+Javascript using Set, List

Tags: javascript

i just want to iterate over a List or a Set from Data of my DomainModel.

```
 for(var report in ${reportInstanceList.toSet()}) {

       var postalcode= report.postalcode;
       alert(postalcode);

     }
```

> But i get always from Mozilla:
>       "missing ] after element list"  ---->
>       "for(var report in [fire.report : 4, fire.report : 1, fire.report : 5, fire.report :  2, fire.report : 3]) {..."
>
> from Opera: 
>       "Syntax error at line 18 while loading: syntax error
>       t in [fire.report : 1, fire.report :
>   --------------------^"
>
> I tried also with toList(). And i tried another syntax, like :
>       '${reportInstanceList.toSet()}'
>       "${reportInstanceList.toSet()}"
>
> But it dont work, it must be a little problem but i dont get it...

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to mix two languages as if they were running in the same environment. You have to render legal javascript, which is running on the client machine, and knows nothing about groovy or domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to write some Javascript in a GSP Template? If so, you need to convert your Groovy object into something your Javascript code can work with, typically JSON:

```
<%! import grails.converters.JSON %>

...

    for(var report in ${reportInstanceList as JSON}) {
    ...
```

UPDATE:

Turns out the serialization worked fine, but the iteration over the array was wrong. Use something like this:

```
var reportsList = ${reportInstanceList as JSON};
for (var i=0; i<reportsList.length; i++) {
    var report = reportsList[i];

    // do something with your report, e.g.
    alert(report.postalcode);
}
```

You generally should not use the `for (… in …)` method to iterate over an Array.

Comment: Yes thats right, but when i call this:

...
          for(var report in ${reportInstanceList as JSON}) {
           
        alert(report.postalcode);
}...

I get "undefined", so he dont understand that the variable "report" is a instance of a Report.class. How can i fix this?

More info: All reports have a postalcode, and i can get access to it with :
    ${reportInstance.postalcode}

Comment: Ok, so we are back at @Dave Newton's comment: are you trying to access a Groovy class in Javascript? That is not going to work, I am afraid. You probably would want to share data objects, try something like `for(var postalcode in ${reportInstanceList*.postalcode as JSON}) { alert(postalcode); }`

Comment: ok, my fault. I didn´t explain my problem very well. I have a reportInstanceList, and this contains many reportInstances. Each reportInstance contains as variable : postalcode, street, number e.t..I want to iterate over my reportinstanceList and get from each ReportInstance, all these informations and save it to a list

Comment: Mozilla throws this in his console:  for(var report in [{"class":"st.report","id":1,"authorname":"Mike","city":"New-York", "postalcode": 42343 .... when i call -->for(var report in ${reportInstanceList as JSON})<--. But how can i get all this information to a javascript variable? I mean the (postal, city...) in each iteration, for all reports

Comment: I tried this too: for(var report in ${reportInstanceList as JSON}) {var postal =report["postalcode"]; alert(postal);} I get always "undefined"

Comment: Ah, now I get it: the serialization works fine but you are not correctly iterating over the array. I will add an update to my answer.